# What am I doing wrong with my drop down menu?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create my first drop down navigation menu with CSS, I have always been slightly opposed to drop down menus, so I haven't really given this a try before now.

I am able to get my drop down menu to work okay in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE something is very wrong. http://arcwebsolutions.net/barnes/demo.php

If you opened that page with IE or Mozilla, it looks like the drop down menu is being thrown 544px to the right of where it needs to be, but in Chrome it is positioned fine.

I have a feeling it is something very simple, like a position: relative tag is misplaced. I am not sure, and I am getting pretty frustrated trying to figure this out.

CSS

```
#nav {margin: 0 auto; width: 100%;background: #111; }
#nav ul {height: 40px; width: 952px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; text-align: center;background: url(images/navbg.jpg); vertical-align:middle;}
#nav ul li {position: relative; display: inline; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
#nav ul li a {float: left; width: 136px;font-size: 14px;font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;color: #afafaf; display: block; line-height: 40px; text-shadow:2px 2px 3px #000; -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;transition: all .2s ease-out;}
#nav ul li a:hover {background: #0c0c0c;transition: all .2s ease-out;-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;}
#nav ul li ul {padding: 0;position: absolute;top: 40px;left: 544px;width: 180px;-webkit-box-shadow: none;-moz-box-shadow: none;box-shadow: none;display: none;opacity: 0;visibility: hidden;}
#nav ul li ul li {background: #111; height:40px;line-height:40px;display: block; color: #fff;text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;}
#nav ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
#nav ul li:hover ul {display: block;opacity: 1;visibility: visible;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="nav" class="width">
<ul class="shadow2">
<li>
<a href="#"><span class="title fade">Home</span></a>      
</li>
<li>
<a href="#"><span class="title fade">Services</span></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#"><span class="title fade">Projects</span></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#"><span class="title fade">Parts</span></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#"><span class="title fade">Gallery</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li>Classic Cars</li>
      <li>Metal Work</li>
      <li>Diesels</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#"><span class="title fade">Blog</span></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#"><span class="title fade">Contact</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

What have I done?! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your drop-down menus are children of the first level li.

However, this ones are styled

```
#nav ul li {
    position: relative; 
    display: inline;
```

so they have no width. change it to

```
#nav ul li {
    position: relative; 
    display: inline-block;
```

Now that they have width, they are correctly positioned. your ul doesn't need a calculated left, that was anyway a nightmare for an maintenable approach

```
#nav ul li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 544px;    // No   !!
    left: 0px;
    ....
```

Comment: Beautiful! Inline-block, wow. Never would have thought of that.

Just one thing, when I add the above code, it throws my nav slightly off to the right by about 50px...